Can non-mosaic prophecy resurrect forgotten halacha?
There's a well known rule that after Moshe Torah can only be determined via the intellect, prophecy is no longer admissable in this realm.
What about divine communication to reinstate forgotten halachos?
There seems to be a contradiction in this matter.
B Temurah 16a disallows it whereas B Megillah 3a seems to allow for it.
Solutions?
(Not my contradiction but I am looking for a distinction. Something other than saying that the Megillah gemara really means via their intellect)

Ben Yehoyada says that the circumstances in Megillah were different because those letters weren't truly lost. The Luchos, as well as Moshe's original Sefer Torah, were still extant in the Aron that Yoshiyahu hid away. In theory, they could have revealed the location for the Jews to dig it up and discover the letters without violating the principle in Temurah. They just took the shorter route of revealing their existence without necessitating the excavation. But it was a revelation of fact, not a prophetic law.
The Lubavitcher Rebbe suggests that they could have been forgotten even earlier, with the death of Moshe, because the Jews in the desert had no use for written communication, so they wouldn't have been familiar with the written letter variations and wouldn't have thought to reference the Sefer Torah once they'd forgotten the very concept of final letters.
